# Connection between the nullspace of a matrix and the implicit equations of a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I am trying to refresh my Linear Algebra and I am having some problems with the different expresions of a subspace. My problem has to do with an algorithm I've been given to find the implicit equations that define a subspace $V$, assuming you know a basis of $V$.

So assume you have some subspace $V$ with a base $\cal{B}_V$. You define a matrix $B$  such that each row contains a vector of  $\cal{B}_V$. Suppose $C$ is defined as a matrix whose columns form a basis of the subspace of solutions of $BX=0$. Then, $C'x$, with $x = (x_1, x_2, ... )'$, are the implicit equations of $V$. Why is that? Maybe is super simple, but honestly I am stuck.

Edit: forgot to traspose a matrix

Comment: You are assuming that V is a subspace of $R^N$ and that the Matrix $B$ is constructed with the components with respecto to the canonical basis, isn't It?

Comment: @AntonioJPan Yes. Sorry if my question is obvious, but I have been trying to understand it for a while and I just don't see it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to find the implícit equations is to consider a matrix with columns made with the components of the basis vectors and add a column with variables $x_1,...,x_n$. You want this matrix to have rank $r$, the number of elements of the basis. So you take $n-r$ minors of rank $r+1$ to be $0$, and these are the implicit equations.

**Edited:**
My interpretation of your construction is as follows. You are assuming, together with what I wrote in the comment, the standard metric in $\mathbb{R}^N$. Then, your space of solution of $BX=0$ is the orthogonal complement to $V$. By constructing the matrix $C$ and computing $C' X=0$ you are taking the orthogonal of the orthogonal, so you are recovering a description of your original subspace $V$.

I don't like this procedure, since you have to compute a basis of a subspace, what I find a more difficult problem that writing the implicit expression.

Comment: I am interested in why the method I described is correct. The reason I was given this method is because it permits to easily perform the task using software, like Matlab.

Comment: I worked with a concrete example and, yeah, it works, but I would be unable to really explain why. Can you help?

Comment: Ok, I will think It tomorrow.

Comment: @iamanoob I have added an explanation of your method

Comment: Hmm.. I have to think more in depth but I think I am in the pat of understanding it.. thank you for your time

Comment: Each row of $B$ is made with components of a basis element. So $BX=0$ is a list of implicit equations for the orthogonal space. If the first vector is $b_1=(b_1^1,\ldots,b_1^N)$ then the first equation of $BX=0$ is $\sum b_1^i x^i=\langle b_1,X \rangle=0$...